# "ARIBA PO Receipt" email field not getting transferred to Ariba vendor from Apex through MDG

Tags: sap-ariba

APEX vendor "ARIBA PO Receipt email"  field  is not getting transferred to Ariba vendor via MDG. This email address is necessary to allow an Ariba vendor to receive emails of PO instead of having to print  the PO and send the PO to the vendor. Example for ZZ vendor has a vendor email address ZZ@gmail.com that is in APEX but  is not being passed to Ariba.

I tried fetching if any fields are present in lfa1 tables or lfb1 tables with Ariba PO Receipt email but I cannot see them